# Can I use a PLL to generate the *phase* component of an SSB signal?

Tags: pll

I want to use Kahn's method of Envelope Elimination and Restoration (EER) to produce a single-sideband, supressed-carrier (SSB) signal. Kahn simply clipped a low-level SSB signal, but I wonder if it isn't possible to use a PLL in this application.

Knowing the quadrature components of the input signal (I,Q), it seems one should be able to calculate the instantaneous frequency that corresponds to the time-varying phase (phase = arctan(Q/I)) and apply it to the VCO in a PLL that uses the carrier frequency as its reference.

Any ideas?